# Как проверить через bash, запущен ли контейнер?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, docker

```
blue_is_run=$(docker exec blue echo 'yes' 2> /dev/null || echo 'no')
```

Есть код, который проверяет запущен ли контейнер по полному наименованию. Т.е. если запущен контейнер blue - он выдаст `yes`. Как сделать поиск по контейнеру, в середине которого есть текст **-blue-**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список запущенных контейнеров выдаёт команда [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).

Простейший вариант:

```
docker ps | grep -- '-blue-' > /dev/null && echo yes || echo no
```

По-умолчанию `docker ps` выдаёт довольно большую таблицу сведений о контейнерах.

Можно уменьшить объем выдачи, чтобы греп искал именно в том поле, которое нужно:

1. Только имена запущенных контейнеров

   ```
   docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | grep -- '-blue-'
   ```
2. Только образы, из которых контейнеры созданы

   ```
   docker ps --format '{{.Image}}' | grep -- '-blue-'
   ```

Полный список переменных в формате: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting

Comment: grep -q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output

Comment: docker ps --format '{{.Names}} {{.Status}}' | grep -qi "$container_name up"

Comment: @Ivan так как ТС просил найти паттерн *внутри* имени, то ваше выражение нужно переписать как `grep -qi -E ".*${container_pattern}.* up"`